# nginx treats websocket API data as http requests

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a reverse proxy for an API at work with NGINX and node.js using AWS Lightsail, but NGINX doesn't appear to be handling the initial setup of the web socket connection correctly.

When I look in my access.log/error.log files, I can see that 
1. There are no errors
2. The  JSON formatted data I'm sending across my connection is visible inside the access.log file- something I don't think should show up there.

At first glance, it looks like nginx is trying to handle my data as if it were an HTTP request.

Using the net module from node, I receive this response on my client side app indicating that something went wrong, which makes sense if we assume that nginx is trying to handle my API data (JSON) as an http request.

```
Received: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 06 Oct 2019 15:59:58 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 182
Connection: close

<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The client side websocket, which thinks it's receiving JSON, immediately throws an error and closes.

It looks to me like NGINX is failing to redirect API data to node.js, but I really don't know why.

I've tried just about everything in my configuration files to get this working. This setup got me to where I am now.

```
 server {

        listen 80;
        server_name xx.xxx.xxx.xx;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        }

}
```

I've already confirmed that the API works when I open up port 4000 (the one node.js is listening on). When I switch back to port 80, the client connection callback function fires. This at least superficially indicates that the initial connect has taken place. From there everything stops working though.

EDIT: I'm can't find any reference to an initial http request in wireshark, and fiddler doesn't seem to detect any requests period from my client side node process.

Comment: Web socket connections start out as HTTP requests.  Your client is throwing an error, not because it received unexpected data, but because the server gave it a `400` rather than handling the upgrade request to a web socket connection.  In any case, can you show the full request data that lead to the response you show above?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm having trouble actually seeing my traffic. If I'm able to look at it'll I'll definitely provide the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using the Node socket module, which does NOT implement web sockets. Instead this creates an interface for simple TCP, and not web sockets. This is really important because these two things are VERY different. TCP operates at a fundamentally lower level than HTTP, and certainly much lower than web sockets, which start out as HTTP connections and are upgraded to create a web socket connection.

This can be very confusing since when you're working on localhost, since these TCP connections will seemingly do exactly what you want. The problems begin when you try to set up a reverse proxy or something similar in Nginx or Apache. Neither of these are meant to be used at the level of TCP, and operate within the domain of HTTP instead. So simply put, trying to use TCP sockets in a reverse proxy will lead to nothing but frustration, and as far as I'm aware, is actually impossible within the context of Apache and Nginx.

If you're looking for an implementation of web sockets, check out the `WS` (short for web sockets) module on NPM, which was what I actually needed.